# Rails console: backtrace brakes text formatting

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-console

Every time I see an exception in Rails console, it breaks console output.

[image]

Cursor is placed on the last line of exception, and after I press Alt+Backspace it deletes part of output. After pressing Enter formatting is back to normal. As far as I understand it, there are some escape characters in these lines which aren't handled properly by the terminal.

There is no issue with pure `irb` console.

How do I fix that?

Comment: Are you on Ubuntu or using Spring? Both can cause similar issues with certain versions of Ruby and Rails. Do you have the option to run Ruby 2.2?

Comment: OS X, iTerm 2. `Ruby 2.1.1p76`, `Rails 4.1.6`. So you suggest I try updating to Ruby 2.x?

Comment: Ruby is the easiest thing in your stack to update/change, so I would start there. And irb lives in ruby. If that fails, you could try `gem "pry"`.